# Can AWS SES be set to default send with dedicated IP address or does each email have to have the X-SES-CONFIGURATION-SET?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ip, ip-address, amazon-ses

I have a project sending emails using AWS SES. To prevent emails bouncing due to blacklisted IP I am trying to set up dedicated IP.

I followed the instructions on the [developer guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/dedicated-ips.html) and have successfully set up, warmed-up two IP addresses and created them in a dedicated-pool and associated configuration set.

Can SES be set up so that ALL emails are sent from dedicated IP by default or does each email have to set with the X-SES-CONFIGURATION-SET header?

Comment: I think you can add both the dedicated IP to ses-default-dedicated-pool this should allow you to send emails from dedicated ip even if you don't add the config set.

Comment: @JamesDean - that's what I thought was the case. However, looking at the SNS for successfully sent emails the "sourceIp" is not my dedicated IP in the default-pool.

Comment: Here is the related message info (with generic values) from the successfully sent SNS, where the sourceIp does not equal any of my expected IP addresses in my default pool: "source":"email@myUrl.com","sourceArn":"arn:aws:ses:name:123456798:identity/myUrl.com","sourceIp","1.136.132.3"

Comment: the sourceIP isn't the actual IP which deliver the email, it's the IP from which SES receives the email from client and then uses it's own IP to deliver it, https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/notification-contents.html I don't know which field tells that but if you see the message header from the recipient mailbox that will confirm it.

Comment: @JamesDean - you are right - I have been looking at the wrong IP on properties. When I view the internet headers i see that X-SES-Outgoing has the date and the dedicated IP address for the pool that I expected.